# postgresql: Trigger function not firing

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I have two tables as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE public.main_tab (
    smid serial4 NOT NULL,
    smgeometry public.geometry(point, 32639) NULL,
    specific_id int4 NULL,
    mother_tab_smid int4 NULL,
    no_pw int4 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT main_tab_pkey PRIMARY KEY (smid),
    CONSTRAINT u_main_tab_smgeometry UNIQUE (smgeometry)
);

CREATE TABLE public.rel_tab (
    smid int4 NOT NULL,
    no_pw int4 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT rel_tab_pkey PRIMARY KEY (smid)
);
```

There is a foreign key between these two tables as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE public.main_tab ADD CONSTRAINT main_tab _fk_1 FOREIGN KEY (specific_id) REFERENCES public.rel_tab(smid) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

I have written a before trigger to update no_pw in the main table, when specific_id changes as follows:

```
create trigger specific_id_change before
insert or update of specific_id on public.main_tab 
for each row execute function main_tab_specific_id_changed();
```

and the trigger fucntion is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.main_tab_specific_id_changed()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE res rel_tab%rowtype;
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO res FROM rel_tab WHERE rel_tab.smid = NEW.specific_id;
    NEW.no_pw = res.no_pw;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$function$
;
```

Everything is ok to this point.
I have another table that is defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE public.mother_tab (
    smid serial4 NOT NULL,
    smgeometry public.geometry(point, 32639) NULL,
    no_pw int2 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT mother_tab_pkey PRIMARY KEY (smid),
    CONSTRAINT u_mother_tab_smgeometry UNIQUE (smgeometry)
);
```

I have written an after trigger to update mother_tab.no_pw, when main_tab.no_pw is updated as follows:

```
create trigger no_pw_changed after
insert or update of no_pw on public.main_tab 
for each row execute function main_tab_no_pw_changed();
```

and the function is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.main_tab_no_pw_changed()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin
    raise notice 'inside trigger main_tab_no_pw_changed';
    update mother_tab set no_pw = NEW.no_pw where mother_tab.smid = NEW.mother_tab_smid;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$function$
;
```

The problem is that when I update main_tab.specific_id, main_tab.no_pw is updated (using trigger specific_id_change), however, mother_tab.no_pw is NOT update, because the trigger (no_pw_changed  on main_tab) is not fired.

HOWEVER, if I update main_tab.no_pw directly, with an update statement (e.g. update main_tab set no_pw = 10 where smid = 5), the trigger is fired and mother_tab.no_pw is updated.

Can anybody tell me why this trigger is not fired in the first case?

Regards